# What do I buy to suck up a large amount of water and empty it into the sink?

Tags: hvac, water, drain

I would rather have the machine suck the water in at one end and empty it out into the sink via the other end without me having to transfer it myself, if possible. I've seen shop vacs but they aren't right for this situation. I have to empty a large amount of clean water every night now indoors and I'm using a bucket but there must be a tool for this, right?

Comment: Purchasing help is off topic please edit and ask for other advice or the post will be deleted.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the situation? It sounds like you could be in need of a sump pump, or a floor drain somewhere, instead of a bucket or a shop vac. Depending on the details, this could be on topic, if it isn't simply just a "what do I buy for..." question.

Comment: @EdBeal  'Category of tool' should be ok as in "does a thing exist that does this".  What's not ok is "Kenmore vs LG" or "does 1000bulbs do free shipping ever".

Comment: @Harper the question is what to buy, but I felt the question although vague could be answered.

Comment: Noticed that you had this tagged hvac - are you looking for a [condensate pump](https://www.google.com/#q=condensate+pump&tbm=shop)?

Comment: a pump maybe???

Comment: Welcome to SE. How exactly is a wet/dry vac with pumping capability not right for this situation? Please edit your question to clarify that point and explain better what you're doing. As it is, I'm inclined to close it as unclear/too broad.

Comment: Please be less mysterious. Are you emptying a dehumidifier, or what?

Answer (score 2):

> **What do I buy to suck up a large amount of water and empty it into the sink?**

A pump.

---

The normal way to deal with household appliances that produce low-temperature near-normal ph waste-water is to connect them to a drainage system.

If you need something that will "suck up" water your choices are limited to pumps or siphons (including self-starting siphons). If your accesssible drainage/disposal point is higher than the collection point, the only way to "suck up" the water is using a pump designed for the specific purpose - volume, flow rate, acidity, height and other factors may affect the solution.